# callbackurl while connecting to vso using oAuth

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to connect to VSO using oAuth.
First step is to register our app and configure a call back url.
I am creating a console application to test the connectivity. 
Please let me know how to configure the callback url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please take note that: Right now, it is only supported to register web application, it is impossible to register a console app.

So, you need to have a web app first, you can download and use this sample project for a quick start: https://vsooauthclientsample.codeplex.com/

After you download the app, open it in VS2013 or higher, right-click it in Solution Explorer and select **Publish**.

[image]

On the **Publish Web** page, select **Microsoft Azure Website** option to publish that web app to Azure.

[image]

Then, the web app is published to Azure with the URL similar to: **https://vsodevabc.azurewebsites.net**

And when you register this web app, you can set **Application Website** and **Callback URL** to be the followings. (note: the callback URL should be https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/oauth/callback, where "yoursite" is the name of your Azure web site)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been working with this sample. I have one more question. I understand that I need to deploy this sample on azure website. Does that mean that when I build my application for the sample purpose that also needs to be hosted on azure?

Answer (score 0):

When using VSO (now called Team Services) with oAuth2.0 you do have to provide callback url endpoint that Microsoft's Team Services can call directly. So you need to have your application's callback url endpoint published such as publishing to Azure or Aws or any hosting provider that will allow you to have publically accessible url. In the FAQ under Team Services Rest API, there is mention of this approach for debugging purposes:

Visual Studio Team Services does not allow localhost to be the hostname in your callback URL. You can edit the hosts file on your local computer to map a hostname to 127.0.0.1. Then use this hostname when you register your app. Or, you can deploy your app when testing to a Microsoft Azure website to be able to debug and use HTTPS for the callback URL

[Visual Studio Team Service's Rest API oAuth](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth)