# Oauth Authentication for VSO with WCF service

Tags: wcf, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the following link to implement oAuth authentication for connecting to VSO:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth

It involves creating a azure web site and the token in returned to it which is used for further processing.
My requirement is to create a service which will connect to VSO using oAuth authentication and fetch/create the work items.
I want to know how to configure the call back url in case of using a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please take note that: Right now, it is only supported to register web application, it is impossible to register a WCF service project.

If you would like to register a web application and would like to get the call back URL, please check my reply in this link for the detailed steps: [callbackurl while connecting to vso using oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603820/callbackurl-while-connecting-to-vso-using-oauth)